# Expanding or shrinking an interval slightly

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(I_n)$ and $(J_k)$ be sequences of intervals such that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$. Suppose the $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint. My textbook says "We have $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty I_n\subset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty J_k$. But now, by expanding each $J_k$ slightly and shrinking each $I_n$ slightly, we may suppose that the $J_k$ are open and the $I_n$ are closed."

**My question:** What does that sentence mean? How can you expand each $J_k$ slightly and end up with it being open? How can you shrink $I_n$ slightly and end up with it being closed? My point is that you can expand an open interval slightly so that it becomes closed or shrink a closed interval slightly so that it becomes open. The textbook seems to have it reversed.

Answer (score 1):

$(a,b)$ becomes closed if you shrink it to $[a+\epsilon, b-\epsilon]$ and $[a,b]$ becomes open if you expand it to $(a-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$. You can do a similar thing starting with any interval (half closed intervals, for example).